# Flutter Windows: cannot build App error MSB8066

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop, flutter-windows

I am getting this error while building for windows

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(238,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for 'D:\DSI projects\sanjali_app\build\windows\CMakeFiles\a6c8cc86bdf940a07f4885a881770ba0\flutter_windows.dll.rule;D:\DSI projects\sanjali_app\build\windows\CMakeFiles\9c479cc21d461e620769ab96f5bca778\flutter_assemble.rule' exited with code 1. [D:\DSI projects\sanjali_app\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
Exception: Build process failed.

Answer (score 35):

**Updated Aug 2021**

Faced the same error for couple of hours, and none of the issue on Github or answer on StackOverflow seems to be working for me.

So after my research I found out that there is no specific reason why **Error MSB8066** error occur, but it can be due to space in your project Folder path as mentioned by @aishamhasan or some other undetermined reason. In my case, there is a simple file that is missing.

```
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
[   +2 ms]   [        ] No file or variants found for asset: images/project_app.png.
```

In order to quickly find out what causing this problem, you can run your project from the command line instead of using run functionality on android studio.

```
flutter run -d windows -v
```

And inside your verbose, lookout for any error, or you can directly search for `Error` and then try to figure out what was causing the error.

Followed the same approach and I was able to resolve the error very quickly.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly. The exact error is shown while running this command in terminal. Thanks.

Comment: This solution helps me to know where the issue was. In my case after doing this, only need to perform flutter pub upgrade --major-version due the issue was at some outdated dependencies, specially win32, that was causing the error. Thanks so much again.

Answer (score 15):

Sometimes I get this error too. I have found that it happens whenever I forget to add a final slash "/" when declaring an assets folder in pubspec.yaml. For example:

This will produce the error:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/game_logos
```

Adding the final slash solves the error:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/game_logos/
```

Comment: Yeap, that was it. And just a heads up for others: If you added any asset path to your `pubspec.yaml` and suddenly start to see this error, try this before anything else.

Answer (score 3):

The solution that worked for me is that I deleted build folder/dir from my project

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had an `assets` image that I removed from the folder but had the path in `pubspec.yaml`, so I deleted the path then the app could run in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen for a few reasons, an asset's path is missing the slash:
So:
*assets:
assets/image*

While it should be like this:
*assets:
assets/image/*

With the slash at the end.

The other more normal one, and which could really be causing such an error, could be the following;

The directory your project is in contains a special character, for example:

*C:\Users\Aurélio Fernam\Documents\Projets\my_project*

As you can see, *"Aurélio"* contains a special character. This could be causing this error.

Also try not to have a folder with space in your project path, like this:

*C:\Users\Aurélio Fernam\Documents\Projets\my_project*

Notice that *"Aurélio Fernando/*" besides having a special character, contains a space.

This could also be a trigger.

After having moved the project to a better directory, run flutter clean and run the project normally.

Answer (score 2):

simple steps to remove this error

1)`flutter clean`
2)`flutter pub get`

This will help u to make your project free from this error.

Answer (score 1):

Removing spaces on the Projects Folder Path Solves the Issue.

[Flutter Issues](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/80179)

Comment: mark it as answer if it helped you solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

I got MSB8066 when I generate python bindings, and fixed this by disabling
BUILD_PYTHON_BINDINGS in CMakeLists.txt

Comment: when I build Flann 1.9.1

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the `build` folder in my project fixed the issue for me, you can also run a `flutter clean`, then run your project again.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error

> C:\dev..\client\build\windows\CMakeFiles\0950da8beda6981876b8c7492aa5c9b3\flutter_windows.dll.rule;C:\dev..\client\build\windows\CMakeFiles\4176b1834887218866857c2082a6e590\flutter_assemble.rule"
> �����訫� ��� � ����� 1.
> [C:\dev..\client\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
> Exception: Build process failed.

The problem was in pubspec.yaml, the link to the image was duplicated in assets:

```
assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/images/iconMars40.png
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue due to some errors were there in some of the dart files. Check for red-underlined errors in the dart files you may have missed. These errors don't allow the project to run. After resolving the errors the project is running fine.

Answer (score 0):

Non-Alphanumeric Characters in the project name also cause it.

Answer (score 0):

I played arround with json in my asset folder. I deleted it and missed to remove it from pubspec as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I use:

```
flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Visual Studio [BuildTools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/?q=build%20tools#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2022) and re-installed it again, then it worked.

I only installed BuildTools (not fully installed Visual Studio). So if you installed fully Visual Studio, you can try to uninstall and re-install fully Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

check if you have recently create file or added new dependencies in pubspec.yaml if it's the cas then delete them. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, upgrade packages to latest version in pubspec.yaml solved error.

Answer (score 0):

you can fix with

```
dart fix
```

and reload the project

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I found that it was a missing file "x" that is declared in pubspec.yaml under assets but does not exist in the project folder

Answer (score 0):

In my case. One of my asset folders was missing an ending slash.

```yaml
flutter:
  assets:
    - res/subDir # Changing it to res/subDir/ fixed the issue
```

If that's not your case. You can use the verbose CLI argument to find more detail:

```
flutter run -d win --verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had assets with read-only. I remove read-only, and then everything works fine. Consider this possibility too.

Answer (score -1):

None of the above methods worked for me.
First, I get an export zip file from project. And extract its content.
And open it, instead of the main project.
Only this worked for me after 1 day. But don't know why!

---

UPDATE:
This error fix for me when run Android Studio as administrator.