# Encountering issues when using Images in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Every time I try to get images from the internet or from my assets folder I get the MSB8066 error. Please how can I fix this? Images are a big part of my projects.

My project paths don't have space or special characters in them. I've ran VS code as administrator and, I made sure my pubspec.yaml file is in order (for projects that used an assets folder).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67031371/flutter-windows-cannot-build-app-error-msb8066

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.